# differential equation with $e^{x-t^2/2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, error-function

I don't manage to solve the following DE
$$y''(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}} \,\mathrm{d}t, \quad x > 0 , \quad y(0) = 0 , \quad y'(0) = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

you have $$y''(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}} \,\mathrm{d}t, \quad x > 0 , \quad y(0) = 0 , \quad y'(0) = 0.\tag 1$$  you are looking for a solution of the form $$y(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \, dt \tag 2  $$ differentiating $(2),$  gives $g(x) = y'(x)$ in particular $g(0) = 0. $differentiating once more,you get 
$$g'(x) = y''(x) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^{x-\frac{t^2}{2}}\, dt, \quad g(0) = 0.\tag 3 $$ integrating $(3)$ and using the initial conditions we get $$\begin{align} g(x) &= \int_0^x e^s \left(\int_{-\infty}^{s^2/2} e^{-t^2/2}\, dt\right)\, ds\\
&=\int_{-x^2/2}^0 e^{-t^2/2} \left(\int_{\sqrt{-2t}}^x e^s\, ds\right)\, dt\\
&=\int_{-x^2/2}^0 e^{-t^2/2} \left(e^x - e^{-\sqrt{-2t}}\right)\, dt\\
\end{align} $$

Comment: how did you manage to do that change of variable, please kindly advice

Comment: @leibnizzzz, fubini's theorem, i think. you can the order of integration.

Comment: The region seems wrong

Comment: I have added my working

Comment: @leibnizzzz, i dont want you editing my answer. i have removed your edit.

Comment: i manage to do it separately

Comment: @leibnizzzz, i am sorry. do you know that you can answer your own question?